# How to execute SQL files outside of spring application using maven command?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot application which is using Postgresql and also maven. It uses the Flyway migration to migrate database changes. I want to have a specific SQL file and run it by a command to insert some records for configuration whenever I want.

Could you please help me to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The specific topic is detailed here [Spring Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

Basically set the initialization values as you require:

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
....
```

E.g. (there are much more options) if you place into resources the file `data.sql` it will be executed and you can add your fixtures.

For specific **Flyway** migrations you should check [Execute Flyway Database Migrations on Startup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup).

Basically you add every new migration version script and it will be checked for every deployment.

Comment: I want to run it by command and also whenever I want, not on the startup

Comment: What is the reason for doing that? If you decouple the execution of migrations with your codebase, a non-automatic human intervention will be necessary (which will cause you problems). If it is a one-time intervention to solve a problem, use the standard tools you already have available, don't mess up your codebase with it.

Comment: Actually, I want to have a sql file for adding the Super Admin account. What is your suggestion?

Comment: Follow the answer suggestion adding the migration `insert into users (...) select 'admin', ... from dual where not exists (select 1 from users where id = 'admin'` or so. But remember, only migrations required by codebase changes should be added to the codebase (do not include scripts to solve specific customer/deployment issues).